# What is Mumford & Sons' song "Holland Road" about?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

Mumford & Sons are critically acclaimed for their lyric writing ability. What is the song [*Holland Road*](http://www.metrolyrics.com/holland-road-lyrics-mumford-sons.html) in the album [*Babel*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Mumford-Sons-Babel/master/473200) about ?

Comment: Have the band ever commented on the lyrics ?

Comment: Just hints towards the fact that Mumford was a drummer for Laura Marling back in the days . Holland road is a road in west London I think.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible meaning of the title could be about **Holland Road** in London where lies **Universal Music** headquarters (at the corner of Kensington High Street).

[image: Universal Music]

Wikipedia article for [Holland Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holland_Road,_London) also says:

> Corporate Headquarters of Universal Music are actually located on the corner of Holland Road and Kensington High Street. **Universal Music is the UK’s leading music company** and is home to major artists from Queen to **Mumford & Sons** —who wrote a song entitled "Holland Road"— and The Rolling Stones.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comment from a poster (Abu Bardewa) on youtube who offers an explanation, that the song is about the people who kept cutting him down, but he kept on believing and succeeded in the end. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EALWGx4cnUw.  Seems an OK explanation to me.